# Get iv string when performing Crypt::encrypt in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I am trying to make cross domain ajax call with username and password encrypted by Laravel, but I cannot figure out the way to find IV string generated during Crypt::encrypt operation. What would be the best way to find that?

Update (added code):

```
$encUsername = Crypt::encrypt($username);
$encPassword = Crypt::encrypt($password);

JavaScript::put([
  'username' => $encUsername,
  'password' => $encPassword
]);
```

Comment: Got code? Add it to the question.

Comment: What do you need the IV for?

Comment: @ScottArciszewski I need it for php `mcrypt_decrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , string $mode [, string $iv ] )` function on the other end (outside laravel app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/06edd84c6ba0520ad2eefd6c8d6633f372dca0de/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L62-L84), the result of `encrypt()` is base64 encoded JSON data:

```
    $iv = random_bytes($this->getIvSize());
    $value = \openssl_encrypt(serialize($value), $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);

    // ...
    $mac = $this->hash($iv = base64_encode($iv), $value);
    $json = json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac'));

    // ...
    return base64_encode($json);
```

You'll want to `base64_decode` and `json_decode` the value then use the `iv` key.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I implemented it correctly:
`$json = base64_decode($encUsername);
    $iv = json_decode($json);
    $iv = $iv->iv;`